# How to read all the values of an atrribute under an XML tag [dom4j]?

Tags: java, xml, sax, dom4j

I am using dom4j library(SAXReader) in java and want to know how can I read and fetch all the values of an XML attribute present in the child XML tags of some parent XML tags.
for eg.

```
....
<ParentTag1>
 <ChildTag1 SomeAttributeName1 = "val1">....</ChildTag1>
 <ChildTag2>...</ChildTag2>
 <ChildTag3 SomeAttributeName1 = "val2">...</ChildTag3>
</ParentTag1>
....
<ParentTag2>
 <ChildTag1 SomeAttributeName2 = "val1">....</ChildTag1>
 <ChildTag2>...</ChildTag2>
 <ChildTag3 SomeAttributeName2 = "val2">...</ChildTag3>
</ParentTag2>
......
```

Let's say the attribute is `SomeAttributeName1`
Questions:

- How can I collect all the values of `SomeAttributeName1` to a list or set ? eg. value set/list = {'val1', 'val2'}

  - While collecting the values for `SomeAttributeName1`, I want to make sure that I only look into child tags of a particular parent tag(here, only look into child tags of `<ParentTag1>` ) and not the complete XML, is it possible to do so ? If yes, please explain your answer using the same ?
  - Following above question, which is faster/efficient and why - reading child elements of `<ParentTag1>` OR reading complete XML to look for the values of `SomeAttributeName1` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since DOM4J has built-in XPATH support, using that is probably the best apprach:

```
    List<String> values = doc.selectNodes("//ParentTag1//@SomeAttributeName1")
            .stream()
            .map(node -> node.getText())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The XPATH expression selects all **Attribute** nodes in all elements that have an ancestor element named **ParentTag1**.